# Rename a static method with __asm__("name") to get called from vector table

Tags: c++, templates, attributes, g++, inline-assembly

I want to give a static member another name, so it can be linked in a vector table which is elsewhere predefined. The idea is simply to call my static method from the vector table. This works quite well with static methods from non templated class *if* the declaration and definition is divided.

But I want to have a templated class, so I have no idea how I can write that.

Q1: Why **asm**("name") did not work for definitions? Any tricks here?

Q2: How can I write a templated definition of a static class method? The problem is that I have no call from my source to it, because it should only be linked in a vector table. Also I have no knowledge at this place with which parameter it will be instantiated.

```
//non templated variant
class Bla
{
    public:
        // with attributes it seems to work
        void f1() __attribute__((deprecated))
        {
        }

        void f2() __asm__("__newName_f2"); // works


        // compiles without error or warning, but no renaming happens!
        void f3() __asm__("__newName_f3") __attribute__(( __used__, __externally_visible__)) {}  
};

void Bla::f2() {} // definition for renamed function, OK works!

template <typename T>
class Blub
{
    void b1() __asm__("__blub_b1") ;
};

// How to write a templated method?
// The instance must be visible without a call,
// because it should be linked in a vector table
template <typename T>
void Blub<T>::b1() {}


int main()
{
    Bla bla;
    Blub<int> blub;
}
```

Update:

The problem relates to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88061 and should be solved with release of gcc 14.